# ksh: is it safe to concatenate a really long string

Tags: bash, ksh

I have a very large data file (2GB-3GB). I need to parse some data out of it and check if there is a duplication. So I have a empty string to start with, so data that I parse out from input file, will be check against this string. If it is not already there, append it. This string can potential be **very very** long. Is it dangerous?

Comment: Unless you have no control over how your 'very large data file' is being constructed, trying to find duplicate data in 1 long string seems like a bad idea.  And to try and perform such processing in a shell seems really bad ;-( ... (The std Unix toolbox approach would be to turn the data into a bunch of lines and use `sort| uniq -c` processing to find duplicates).... Maybe if you take the time to construct a very small sample case (and use formatting) that illustrates the problem you're trying to solve, you'll get some good feedback on alternate approaches to solving  your problem. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter: I guess, instead of append to a string, what about append to a tmp file. so every time I parse out data, I would do `cat $tmp_file | grep $data`, if the grep return `empty`, then I append `>>` to the file. You think that is a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not dangerous. You just might have not enough memory to store a very very long string. So will encounter out of memory error.

Comment: I guess, instead of append to a string, what about append to a tmp file. so every time I parse out data, I would do `cat $tmp_file | grep $data`, if the grep return empty `""`, then I append `>>` to the file. You think that is a better idea?

Comment: That might work, but will be extremely inefficient and I guess slow as hell. Ideally you should have a sorted list of strings and compare every next one with previous to detect a duplicate. Sorting that file is another problem tho. Nothing that is easy to implement comes to mind, except maybe working with some lightweight database like `sqlite`. But again, shell doesn't seem to be the right solution for this. I'd say look at Python or Perl, then C/C++/Java/Ruby (whatever you know)...

Comment: Yeah, as a quick try - run your parsing and pipe the output to "sort -u", which is supposed to sort data and filter out duplicates (with `-u` flag). That might work, but I am not sure if `sort` is smart enough to handle gigabytes of data.